# SQL Server - Search for specific column based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, field

I got very wide table of monthly indexes look like:

```
index_id | ... | Mar2009 | Apr2009 | May2009 | ... | Feb2010 |
1        | ... | value1  | value2  | value3  | ... | value11 |
```

There are 180 columns, names are in series what represent month and year (Mar2009, Apr2009, ...), and there are about 5000 records, this table is updated monthly.

I also got second table with data like:

```
index | some other data | index_id | saledate | saleprice | estimated price |
1234  | other data ...  |        1 | 03/05/09 |       100 | ??????????????? |
```

(about 1 milion records) and I need to delivered full record based on index including `estimated_price` which is calculated as:
`saleprice * ( value1 / value11 )` value1 because saledate id in March 2009, value11 because of current month.

I got 2 options, both need to access specific column based on value, second can have work around:

1. Calculate on fly ( and **how I can access correct column in indexes table based of saledate and current data** ) - be aware that data table is big and indexes are not samll either
2. When update indexes table run a job to calculate estimated price place it in data table, how ever same question as above ( **how access correct column in indexes table based of saledate** )

Second solution looks more effective at first look, however I afraid that that update process can take too long... I consider a stagging table that will convert wide index table to long table like:

```
index_id | date_from_column | index_value |
```

this way it could be easier to merge tables, however I will need to after update indexes table TRUNCATE long table and run 180 INSERTs like:

`INSERT INTO long_table SELECT index_id, 'Mar2009' AS date_from_column, Mar2009 AS index_value FROM indexes_table`

where each next INSERT will have next column name form indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, the problem you have is that your design is not normalized and the consequence is that the queries to extract information are more difficult. Specifically, the first table should be structured as:

```
Create Table MonthlyIndexes As
    (
    index_id int not null
    , date datetime not null
    , value ...
    , Primary Key ( index_id, date )
    , Constraint CK_MonthlyIndexes_Date Check ( DatePart(d, date) = 1 )
    )
```

```
index_id | date     | value
--------   --------   -------
1        | 20090301 | ...
1        | 20090401 | ...
...
```

Now the query to retrieve the information you want becomes simpler:

```
Select S.saleprice * ( MStart.value / MEnd.value )
From Sales As S
    Join MonthlyIndexes As MStart
        On MStart.date = DateAdd(d, -DatePart(d, S.saledate) + 1)
    Join MonthlyIndexes As MEnd
        On MEnd.date = DateAdd(d, -DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1)
```

Barring a restructing of your schema, you can simulate the proper design like so (assuming SQL Server 2005+):

```
With Indexes As
    (
    Select index_id, Cast('20090301' As datetime) as date, Mar2009
    From MonthlyIndexes
    Union All
    Select index_id, Cast('20090401' As datetime) as date, Apr2009
    From MonthlyIndexes
    ....
    Union All
    Select index_id, Cast('20100201' As datetime) as date, Feb2010
    From MonthlyIndexes
    )
Select S.saleprice * ( MStart.value / MEnd.value )
From Sales As S
    Join MonthlyIndexes As MStart
        On MStart.date = DateAdd(d, -DatePart(d, S.saledate) + 1)
    Join MonthlyIndexes As MEnd
        On MEnd.date = DateAdd(d, -DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1)
```

If the monthly indexes table is large, you could do period updates of a normalized table and use that for your query.

Another solution is to periodically update a staging table with the data structured properly using a query akin to the Union All query in my CTE. If the data is added once a month, you could even add a schedule stored proc that checks whether there is a column for a given month and appends that month's data. That would involve dynamic SQL which I'd normally recommend against however for a maintenance solution it might solve the problem (until you convince management to correct the schema).

Comment: First table is a source of data - not my design but need stay that way - I agree that MonthlyIndexes ( my long_table ) is better solution ( the best is to set estimated_price every month ) but problem is how to convert source ( my indexs_table to MonthlyIndexes as staging table or directly to estimated_price ) ?

Comment: @bensiu - How often is the data needed? I.e., can you simply fill/update a staging table using a periodic job using the Union All query I mentioned? Another option of course is a View.

Comment: Indexes should be updated monthly ( there is a risk of dayly too ) - so I looking for most optimal way to UPDATE estimated_price in data_table. Your UNION can be a source of staging table ( optimalized MonthlyIndexes ) and your SELECT statement can be the value source of estimated_price.

Comment: @bensiu - Of course, another solution is to create the table I mentioned, populate it and replace the original table with a view and an Instead Of query that populates the newly structured table against the old interface. That way the existing applications do not know anything has changed, but your query is significantly easier and faster.